# How to create numerical_column in tensorflow when features is just a tensor rather than a dict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to create a `input_fn` for `DNNClassifier` in tensorflow. `DNNClassifier`'s `train` method say as follow,

> `input_fn`: A function that provides input data for training as minibatches. See Getting Started with TensorFlow for more information. The function should construct and return one of the following:
>
> > A 'tf.data.Dataset' object: Outputs of Dataset object must be a tuple (features, labels) with same constraints as below.
> >
> > A tuple (features, labels): Where features is a Tensor or a dictionary of string feature name to Tensor and labels is a Tensor or a dictionary of string label name to Tensor. Both features and labels are consumed by model_fn. They should satisfy the expectation of model_fn from inputs.

It says I can create a `input_fn` which just return `(features, labels)` where `features` is a tensor. But `numerical_column` needs a `key`

Code here

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_DATA/", one_hot=False)

train_x, train_y = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels
train_y = train_y.astype(np.int32)

def train_input_fn(features, labels):
    return features, labels

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("")]

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[10, 10],
    n_classes=10
)

classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda:train_input_fn(train_x, train_y),
    steps=1000
)
```

I got an error

```
ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Right, there's no great special case for only one feature column. Can you just pick an arbitrary name for it, and return a one-element dictionary with that key mapping to your single Tensor?